# How to get a worksheet by name in .NET?

Tags: .net, excel

Being forced from NPOI to microsoft interop, I have to perform a task of finding a certain worksheet in workbook, and then iterate through every row of it.

In NPOI it would be simply `workbook.GetSheet(sheetName);`. What would be the equivalent for this in microsoft interop?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `workbook.Sheets[sheetName];`

**Complete working example:**

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var excelApplication = new Application();
        excelApplication.Visible = true;
        excelApplication.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 3;
        var workbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add();
        var worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet2"];         //<--- desired method
        worksheet.Activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I'm pretty sure you can just do `workbook.Sheets["Sheet2"]`.

Comment: @JeffYates, Dope! +1 Your right... no need to do an extension method. Updated my post to correct for this.

Comment: Looks nice, but why the Add() method?

Comment: @Nordvind, because the snippet isn't opening an excel workbook but creating a new one, thus it's adding it to the excel application.

Comment: I am using <package id="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" version="15.0.4795.1000" targetFramework="net45" /> and I could not use above method. It gives me invalid index error.

Comment: That doesn't work if your worksheet is in Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel, and you might need to to access NamedRanges (just an example). You get a COM incorrect cast exception.